# Visualization of 3D GIS daten with 3D glasses

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d

A colleague of mine wants to inspect 3D aerial photos in 3D with 3d glasses. He thinks he just needs the right 3d Graphics card and monitor with more Ghz - something along the lines of nvidia 3d Gaming cards I imagine. The 3d Visualisation could then be produced automagically without any need for extentions in ArcGIS.

Has anyone any experience with this kind of hardware? what works, what doesn´t what should be avoided at all cost etc?

Comment: This sounds like stereoscopic viewing. Viewing and creating data from it are very different things. I'm not entirely clear on what he wants to do. There's one question here already about related hardware: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19174/are-there-any-3d-gis-which-exploit-consumer-level-3d-hdtvs A couple more about creating data from stereo pairs (41432 & 32685). [ArcScene](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q80000007r000000) lets you do stereo in a couple of ways, but that's an extension. I don't think it's possible without one or third party software.

Comment: downvoter care to speak up?

Comment: I am simply gathering experience at the moment. I have arcscene and can produce 3D Geodaten. But "Real" 3D visualization with glasses it is not! My colleague is trying to produce the 3d Effect with glasses...

Answer (score 1):

As Chris W says, ArcScene is your best bet if you want to stay in the 'Arc' world without 3rd party extensions. You have 3 options to choose from. (View -> View Settings -> Viewing Characteristics -> Stereo View - Method)

Shutter Glasses: Requires the hardware your friend is referring to.

Red/Blue anaglyth: Think old school 3d glasses. Probably not ideal for viewing aerial photography.

Free: 2 images are displayed side by side on screen. You can achieve a (headache inducing) 3d picture by crossing your eyes.